# I'm trying do a button in a responsive layout

Tags: javascript

I'm trying do a button in a responsive layout. It needs to be hidden sometimes and show itself when the screen is small, I see a code that do it with vanilla js. But i'm using typescript, the problem it is in the typing typescript. Can someone help me with that?
thecode

```
function Menu(e){
    let list = document.querySelector('ul');
    e.name === 'menu' ? (e.name = "close",list.classList.add('top-[80px]') , list.classList.add('opacity-100')) :( e.name = "menu" ,list.classList.remove('top-[80px]'),list.classList.remove('opacity-100'))
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193) you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Use css and its [`media` queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries). I don't think you need JS here.

Comment: On a sidenote: You should **prefer if-statements** and **separate statements into the `if` and `else` blocks**, instead of using the ternary and comma operator: You are using _none_ of the returned values of _either_ of the operators. Writing code as suggested is much more common and therefore understandable.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using media queries in CSS to detect the screen width/height and automatically apply the properties you need

You can find various device size and its respective pixel size in height and width, you can use these to set the button visibility as follows

```css
/* by default don't show the button */
.yourElement {
  display: none;
}

/* set display to block to show your element only if the width of the screen is less than or equal to 800px*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .yourElement {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Read more about media queries here [css media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries)

Answer (score 0):

you can use button tag with type as any of the following ("radio,checkbox,etc..") so that you can create responsive buttons. To make the button functionable, you must link any other page with the button tag using inline href.